# Display data with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_COM_MST_DEL(
    @Code AS INT = 0,
    @Name AS VARCHAR(50)= '',
    @Type AS INT =0,
    @Operation AS varchar(20) ='',
    @Message AS VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT,
    @Status AS VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Operation = 'DISPLAY')
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM COM_MST WHERE COM_CTCD = @Type)
        BEGIN
            SET @Status = '0'
            SET @Message = 'NO RECORD FOUND'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SET @Status = '0'
            SET @Message = 'NO RECORD FOUND'
            SELECT * FROM COM_MST WHERE COM_CTCD = @Type
        END
    END
END
```

But when I try to run the procedure.. it shows an error

```
USP_COM_MST_DEL @Operation = 'DISPLAY'
```

Error:

> Procedure or function 'USP_COM_MST_DEL' expects parameter '@Message', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify where the output parameters should go to.

```
declare 
    @Message VARCHAR(200),
    @Status VARCHAR(2) 

exec USP_COM_MST_DEL @Operation = 'DISPLAY', @message output, @status output
```

(which is exactly what the error message is saying)

Comment: above code saying error message 

** Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'. 
**

Answer (score 1):

This is now displaying with no error...

```
exec USP_COM_MST_DEL @Operation = 'DISPLAY',@type=4, @message ='', @status =''
```